# What database systems are fully supported by Entity Framework 6 and/or 7?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Which database systems (relational or NoSql) are supported by Entity Framework 6 and/or 7?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Entity Framework [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907.aspx) has a long list (right hand side) of 3rd party providers. The ones listed today are:

- MySQL Connector/NET
- System.Data.SQLite
- Oracle Data Provider for .NET
- VistaDB
- Devart
- cdata
- OpenLink Software
- IBM
- Sybase SQL Anywhere
- Sybase Adaptive Server Enterprise
- Phoenix Software Solutions
- Synergex
- Firebird
- Npgsql
- NuoDB
- Ritmo for IBM i (DB2)

EF7 is harder to find info for, but here are some links that may help:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/05/19/ef7-new-platforms-new-data-stores.aspx
http://www.infoworld.com/article/2885466/application-development/entity-framework-7-providing-support-for-new-platforms-and-new-data-stores.html

Comment: And EF6 supports: SQL Server, SQL Azure Database and SQL Server Compact