# C# library for connecting different RDBMS

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, oracle, postgresql

I'm currently working on one project. I want to analyze a few things in the database, to see which is faster, more reliable, less resource-consuming.

I would like to create one program in C# and connect five databases. From that program, I will call the procedures and measure the time of execution.

Which library do I use in C# to connect: Microsoft SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL, IBM Db2 with Visual Studio? 
I have found this library on the internet: http://dbnetdata.codeplex.com/
Has anyone used it? Does anyone know about another library?

Comment: Asking for software/library recommendations is off topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: Bad track. If you want to test the relative performances of the databases you should use their native providers, not a one-do-it-all Pretty sure that this approach will require compromises that at the end will affect your measurements

Comment: You could use ODBC (ADO.NET System.Data.Odbc namespace objects) to use any DBMS with and ODBC driver.

Comment: I would recommend `System.Data.Odbc` namespace https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcconnection(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make fair comparisons you should use the native provided libraries.  These are:

> SQL Server:        System.Data.SqlClient
>
> Oracle:            Oracle.ManagedDataAccess
>
> PostgreSQL:        Npgsql
>
> MySQL:             MySQL.Data
>
> IBM DB2:           Sorry don't know never used it!  I hope someone
>   else can supply

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework would be able to connect to those engines.

[What database systems are fully supported by Entity Framework 6 and/or 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30426962/what-database-systems-are-fully-supported-by-entity-framework-6-and-or-7)